# migration - mysql 5.6 -> mariadb 10.1 -> sql errors

Tags: mysql, mariadb

After migrating from `Mysql 5.6` to `MariaDB 10.1` I get these sql errors

## SQL 1

```
SELECT dv.id,IF(de.id IS NULL,0,1) is_attached,dv.time,dv.label,dv.is_pdf_scan,dv.is_pic_low_resolution,dv.file_sha1,dv.file_ext,dv.file_ext_thumb,dv.file_size,dv.file_size_original,dv.file_name,u.name from_name,dv.from_email
FROM `data_voucher` dv
LEFT JOIN `data_voucher_enclosure` de ON de.data_voucher_id=dv.id
LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.id=dv.user_id
WHERE IF(de.id IS NULL,0,1)=0 && dv.time>=1420070400 && dv.time<=1451606399 && dv.client_id=1 && dv.block_id=4544 && dv.is_ready=1 && dv.is_deleted=0
GROUP BY dv.id
ORDER BY dv.time DESC,dv.id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

## error 1

```
#1055 - 'dynaccount.de.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

## SQL 2

```
SELECT dv.id,dv.time,dv.label,dv.is_pdf_scan,dv.file_sha1,dv.file_ext,dv.file_ext_thumb
FROM `data_voucher` dv
LEFT JOIN `data_voucher_enclosure` de ON de.data_voucher_id=dv.id
WHERE de.enclosure_id=270729 && dv.client_id=1 && dv.block_id=4431 && dv.is_ready=1 && dv.is_deleted=0
GROUP BY dv.id
ORDER BY dv.time DESC,dv.id DESC
```

## error 2

```
#1055 'dynaccount.dv.time' isn't in GROUP BY
```

## UPDATE

In `phpmyadmin` I get a similar error when clicking the `databases` tab

## SQL

```
SELECT s.SCHEMA_NAME,s.DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM `information_schema`.SCHEMATA s
GROUP BY BINARY s.SCHEMA_NAME
ORDER BY BINARY `SCHEMA_NAME` ASC
```

## error

```
#1055 - 'information_schema.s.SCHEMA_NAME' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: The comments from MariaDB are correct. The MySQL queries as posted where not following ANSI SQL Standard regarding the GROUP BY.

Comment: Follow ANSI SQL standards? All return values in a GROUP BY have to have a function applied to them so that the GROUP BY knows what to return. Now you return `dv.id,dv.time` while grouping by `dv.time`. ANSI SQL is now wondering: I have 2 `dv.id` records with value 1 with two `dv.time` values, which dv.time do you mean? So you have to give a min/max/avg/etc function to identify the data you want returned for every returned value. It also makes me wonder what MySQL was returning, because it had no way to know which data was correct.

Comment: I still don't get it :)

Comment: what are you actually trying to get as output? show sample data in and out. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, despite on server allowing it. As such, @NorbertvanNobelen is right

Comment: How would you do the two queries compatible with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `SQL_MODE` system variable seems to contain the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enforces strict `ANSI SQL` behavior and disables the MySQL specific `GROUP BY` extensions.

See [also](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), and note that this mode is the default in MySQL 5.7 so you would run into the same sort of problems when moving from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 5.7, too

Comment: How to make my two queries compatible with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` ?